# Android opening two activities simultaneously have race conditions

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, user-interaction

Hi I am developing android application in which I have one base activity(BaseActvitity B).My activity which I start from notification pending intent (Activity A) extends activity B. In activity B I have override `onUserInteraction()` in following way:

```
 @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();

            startActivityC();

    }
```

android inside onCreate :

```
// inside onCreate
if(notificationCondition)
{
    startActivityC(Data)
}
```

Activity C does not extends Base Activity. Not what Happens consider in my application one activity already open. once I click on notification it calls `onUserInteraction` first before it call onCreate of base activity (which is parent activity for notification). Because of that It opens activity from `onUserInteraction` not from onCreate. And I am not able to get that data wich I am passing from onCreate.I have check with logs it's not coming into `onCreate` once it start new activity from `onUserInteraction`.

Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you starting another `Activity` in `onUserInteraction()`. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Hey hi David thank you for your attention. So What I am trying to do if user is idle for certain amount for time then I am trying show some kind password or authentication process. That's the reason I am starting activity  in `onUserInteraction`  on certain condition bases. Please help me out if you can.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding your architecture. Please post the manifest.